# CBPeripheralManagerState shows always state = off

Tags: objective-c, xcode, bluetooth

So I have this peripheralManager. I want to check, if the State of it is on or not:

```
  if (peripheralManager.state <  CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Bluetooth must be enabled" message:@"To search for pics, you have to enable bluetooth." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [errorAlert show];

    }
```

I'm testing it on my iPhone 5 and the Bluetooth is clearly on. But it shows always, that it is off.

**UPDATE**
How can I fix it?

Comment: When do you check for it? Since it's not a BOOL, but an int, what's its real value? Reseting? Unknown? When do you look for its state?

Comment: I look at it, directly after the app starts. the state is 0.

Comment: Well, it's unknown so... Did you check the Apple Sample code to know when it's checked?

Comment: It's strange. Because the sample.code works well. But there isn't any enabling etc. Because programmatically activating bluetooth doesnt work of course